# How to do Stock Trading Back Test Using Pandas and Basic Iteration?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to estimate a trading strategy, given the amount I invest in a particular stock. Basically when I see "K-Class" is 1, I buy, when I see "K-Class" is 0, I sell. To make that simple engough, we can ignore the open, high, low value. just use the close price to estimate.

We do want to iterate the whole Series, following 1=buy 0=sell, no matter it is right or wrong.

I got a pandas DataFrame with a Series called "K-Class", a boolean, just say 1(buy) and 0(sell)

From the first day the 'K-class' appears 1, I buy, if the second day is 0, I sell 'immediately' at the close price

How can I write a for loop to test the afterall invest money and invest time?(using pandas and python technics)

Pleas feel free to add more variables

I got a

```
invest_amount = 10000
stock_owned = 10000/ p1 #the first day appears 1, return the close price
invest_time = 0

            Time  Close  K_Class
0     2017/03/06  31.72        0
1     2017/03/08  33.99        0
2     2017/03/09  32.02        0
3     2017/03/10  30.66        0
4     2017/03/13  30.94        1
5     2017/03/15  32.56        1
6     2017/03/17  33.31        0
7     2017/03/20  34.07        1
8     2017/03/22  34.40        0
9     2017/03/24  32.98        1
10    2017/03/27  33.26        0
11    2017/03/28  31.60        0
12    2017/03/29  30.36        0
13    2017/03/30  28.83        0
14    2017/04/11  27.01        0
15    2017/04/12  24.31        0
16    2017/04/14  24.22        0
17    2017/04/17  21.80        0
18    2017/04/18  21.20        1
19    2017/04/19  23.32        1
20    2017/04/20  24.43        0
21    2017/04/24  23.85        1
22    2017/04/26  23.97        1
23    2017/04/27  24.31        1
24    2017/04/28  23.50        1
25    2017/05/02  22.57        1
26    2017/05/03  22.67        1
27    2017/05/04  22.11        1
28    2017/05/05  21.26        1
29    2017/05/08  19.37        1
..           ...    ...      ...
275   2018/08/01  13.38        0
276   2018/08/03  12.49        0
277   2018/08/06  12.50        0
278   2018/08/07  12.78        0
279   2018/08/09  12.93        0
280   2018/08/10  13.15        0
281   2018/08/13  13.14        1
282   2018/08/14  13.15        0
283   2018/08/15  12.80        0
284   2018/08/17  12.29        0
285   2018/08/21  12.39        0
286   2018/08/22  12.15        0
287   2018/08/23  12.27        0
288   2018/08/24  12.31        0
289   2018/08/27  12.47        0
290   2018/08/29  12.31        0
291   2018/08/30  12.13        0
292   2018/08/31  11.69        0
293   2018/09/03  11.60        1
294   2018/09/04  11.65        0
295   2018/09/05  11.45        0
296   2018/09/07  11.42        0
297   2018/09/10  10.71        0
298   2018/09/11  10.76        1
299   2018/09/12  10.74        0
300   2018/09/13  10.85        1
301   2018/09/14  10.79        0
302   2018/09/18  10.58        1
303   2018/09/19  10.65        1
304   2018/09/21  10.73        1
```

Comment: First stock purchase day is index 4 (2017/3/13) ??

Comment: Yes, please help.  And I want to sell all stock_owned at the first "0" day at the close price, and buy it with the money at hand the next "1" day, hold it until next "0" day

Comment: Is this a homework assignment?  What class are you taking?

Comment: I am not in any class :), It is a part of my self-motivated project, basically I want to take that response, throw it into Support Vector Machine or sth. else to generate a better trading algorithm.